# Unable to load google News Site in my Android Webview**"https://news.google.com"**

Tags: android, webview, load

Unable to load google News Site in my Android Webview.: 
**"https://news.google.com"**
Other site works well except a few such as google news..
here is my Webview setting. Could anybody help me?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    WV.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
else {
    WV.setWebChromeClient(new myWebChromeClient());
}
WV.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
WV.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
WV.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
WV.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
WV.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
WV.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
WV.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
WV.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
WV.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
WV.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
WV.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
WV.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
WV.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
WV.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { 
 WV.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
}
String ua = WV.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
WV.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua + " NewsZine");

CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    try {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    try {
        WV.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

        Qlog.e(TAG, "exception at pre-fileaccess ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        i
    }
}
```

Comment: I have problem loading this url in my Webview : "https://news.google.com"